# Why is this first line of code important in Python?

Tags: python, datetime

I am currently using [Codeacademy](http://codeacademy.com) to learn Python. It is the first language I have ever tried to learn and I am currently stuck. Now I'm not stuck because I couldn't get past a certain lesson. I'm stuck because I had to do a quick search on the internet to find out what the first line of code was supposed to be. It never said anything about that first line anywhere and I want to know what it's supposed to do. Here is the full code when it is completed, correctly:

```
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()
print now
year = now.year
month = now.month
day = now.day
print year
print month
print day
print str(month) + "/" + str(day) + "/" + str(year)
```

I kept getting an error telling me that datetime is not defined. I finally found that first line by looking through the Q&A section of [Codeacademy](http://codeacademy.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an issue with Codeacademy environment. It may be restricted for educational purposes. The `import` should work in an ordinary Python environment:

```
from datetime import datetime # import `datetime` class from `datetime` module

print(datetime.utcnow()) # call class method
```

`datetime` is a stdlib module. It is always available.

It can also could be written as:

```
import datetime # import module

print(datetime.datetime.utcnow()) # module.klass.klassmethod()
```

Rule of thumb for a well-written Python code: unless it is a builtin function or a Python keyword then you could find where any name that is used in the code were introduced just by looking at the source code.

Module names are introduced using `import` statements at the top of the file with the source code usually.

Make sure there is no `datetime.py` file in your current working directory if you are trying this code on your local computer. Otherwise `import` statement will use it instead of the one from stdlib.

Answer (score 0):

That first line defines datetime (hence the error). More specifically, it imports the datetime object from the datetime module.

More info here:
http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm

Comment: Ohh, thanks. I'm a little more confused now because I removed it and everything worked just fine...

Comment: Yeah, the datetime module is definitely a weird one. You just kind of have to think of it as a methods within an object without a module, like datetime (module) -> datetime (object) -> now(method). Most modules aren't designed like that, fortunately!

Comment: @AaronB: it is common: `time`, `mmap`, `bisect`, `socket`, `select`, `crypt`, `array`, `dis`, `glob`, `platform` and other stdlib modules have functions/classes with the same names as their parent module.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: I used the word 'most' generally referring to modules that you'd be using as a beginner to Python, but you are absolutely correct that there are quite a few modules in the Python lib with this behavior; thanks!